# Reporte en excel php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buen día, tengo el siguiente programa que me hace busquedas a una tabla de mysql y además me genera un reporte en excel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al querer hacer un reporte me lo hace pero además de la tabla del reporte, me añade más cosas..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como se pueden dar cuenta, la tabla del reporte que es la que necesito es la que está sombreada, pero además de esa tabla el documento que descargo me viene con más cosas. **¿CÓMO HAGO PARA QUE EN EL ARCHIVO EXCEL SOLO ME APAREZCA LA TABLA DEL REPORTE?**

A continuación adjunto el código

Este es el index, aquí incluyo el programa php que me realiza la conexión a la base de datos, el php que me realiza la búsqueda de un determinado dato alojado en la base de datos y el php que me descarga el reporte a excel, aquí tambien se encuentran los input, el submit que me realiza una determinada busqueda, el submit que me descarga el reporte excel y la tabla donde se imprimen los datos que busco:

```
 <?php
 include('conex.php'); 
 ?>
 <?php
 include('repor.php');
 ?>
 <title>busqueda</title> 
 <p>
 <form name="form1" method="POST" action="busqueda.php" id="cdr" 
 onKeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) event.returnValue = false;">
 <h2>Buscar Usuario</h2>
 <input name="busca" type="text" id="busqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el día">
 <input name="mes" type="text" id="mesqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el mes">
 <input name="año" type="text" id="añoqueda" placeholder="Ingrese el año">
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Buscar"> 
 <input type="submit" name="reporte" value="Reporte">    
 </p>
 </form>

 <table width="500" border="1" id="tab">
 <tr>
    <td width="60">Día</td>
    <td width="90">Mes</td>
    <td width="90">Año</td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 include('busq.php');
 ?>
 </table>
```

Este es el php que me realiza la busqueda a la base de datos:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 $busca=$_POST['busca'];
 $mes=$_POST['mes'];
 $año=$_POST['año'];

 $con->real_query("SELECT * FROM entrada WHERE dia like '%$busca%' and mes 
 LIKE '%$mes%' and anio like '%$año%'");
 $resultado= $con->use_result();

 while($muestra=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){
 echo'<tr>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['dia'].'</td>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['mes'].'</td>';
 echo'<td>'.$muestra['anio'].'</td>'; 
 echo'</tr>';
 }

 ?>
```

Y este es el php que me hace el reporte a excel, en este caso lo tengo para que me haga el reporte dependiendo de lo que yo escriba en el input dia:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 include('conex.php');
 $output='';
 $busca=$_POST['busca'];

 if(isset($_POST['reporte'])) {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM  entrada where dia like '%$busca%'";
 $result= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
    $output .= '
      <table class="table" bordered="1">
       <tr>
        <th>Dia</th>
        <th>Mes</th>
        <th>Anio</th>
       </tr>

    ';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= '
          <tr>
            <td>'.$row["dia"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["mes"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["anio"].'</td>
          </tr>  

        ';

    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    header("Content-Type: application/xls");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=download.xls");
    echo $output;
 }

 }

 ?>
```

Cualquier ayuda será muy agradecida!

Comment: Julián bienvenido a Stackoverflow. El problema es que **no puedes sacar nada por pantalla previamente cuando usas `header` ([ver lo que dice el Manual al respecto](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php))**.  Podrías intentar poniendo esto `ob_clean();` antes de sacar el Excel, pero no estoy seguro que funcione. Lo correcto sería procesar el archivo Excel desde otro script, el cual no tenga ningún tipo de salida por pantalla, solamente los encabezados y el contenido del archivo. Este script se puede llamar mediante un enlace, o por medio de Ajax.

Comment: El ob_clean(); no funcionó :(   Y lo que me quieres decir es que cree dos form ? uno para la búsqueda en la base de datos y otro para el reporte?

Comment: Más que dos form, se trata de **procesar la salida en un archivo distinto**, por lo que explica el Manual (en el enlace de mi anterior comentario): cuando tú usas `header` en un script, **no puedes tener nada por pantalla antes de `header`**. Dado que ya tienes por pantalla todo lo relativo a la búsqueda, el procesamiento de la misma debería hacerse en un **archivo independiente**, que podrías llamar por Ajax al pulsar en el botón `Buscar` (esta es la forma más elegante de hacerlo), o bien mediante una URL que invoque ese nuevo archivo en el cual creas el Excel.

Comment: Otra opción sería usar la librería [`phpspreadsheet`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/phpspreadsheet). Ojo, no confundir con la librería PHPExcel, la cual es ya obsoleta y no será mantenida.

Comment: Hice lo de la url amigo, ya hago la búsqueda en una página y con un link, al darle click, me envía al script del reporte en excel, mil gracias hermano !

Comment: Me alegro. Si te interesa para mejorar el código, dale un vistazo a Ajax. Mediante su uso podrías hacerlo sin tener que abrir el archivo en otra ventana, activando un botón **`Descargar Excel`** cuando todo esté listo, sin tener que moverte del formulario de búsqueda. Saludos.